# Does anyone know of a program like Elastics for Linux?

Tags: software-recommendation, amazon-ec2

On mac I would use Elastics (http://tundrabot.com/elastics) To kind of, monitor my EC2 instances. Most important to me was that it worked across several accounts and that it allowed me to connect to a running instance via ssh or RDP.

This was the only real feature I care about. I can not always keep the IP address of the server that is running because ec2 is elastic, and it changes frequently.

Is there any tool, like Elastics for linux/unity? Again it should support several accounts and be able to give me the IP addresses of the instance I select.

Comment: I have already tried aws-status. It does not work for me needs. It doesn't tell me the IP addresses, or support several accounts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://github.com/coteyr/unity-ec2-lense

I created a simple unity lens (using singlet) to do what I need. It's working, with more testing and some clean up, it can serve as an example to others.

I will leave the question open a while longer to see if there are any other answers.